# A regex style matching library for generic matching on list items

Tags: clojure

I've seen a library like this around before but then forgotten about what it was called.

You can specify a pattern that matches elements in a list, something along the lines of:

```
(def oddsandevens (pattern (n-of odd? :*) (n-of even? 2) :$))

(pattern-match oddsandevens [1 1 2 2]) => true
(pattern-match oddsandevens [1 1 1 2 2]) => true

(pattern-match oddsandevens [1 1 2 2 2]) => false
(pattern-match oddsandevens [1 1 2]) => false
```

If I'm totally imagining this, can someone shed light on how one might write one of these things?

Comment: Here are the regex projects in clojure available on GitHub https://github.com/search?q=regex&type=Repositories&ref=advsearch&l=Clojure
Hope it can help you find back your library!

Comment: This might be helpful http://brehaut.net/blog/2010/ghosts_in_the_machine . You could potentially use a backtracking state monad to parse the sequence. Not that I've tried (or even know what a backtracking state monad is), but it looks interesting and relevant.

Comment: Or maybe this library https://github.com/jamii/strucjure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More generally, you are asking for an expressive way to *parse* a sequence. There are of course many parsing libraries out there for Clojure, but many of them [complect](http://www.infoq.com/presentations/Simple-Made-Easy) the lexing with the parsing (there may be good reasons for this in terms of optimizing performance), and so can only be used on strings. You might have to look outside the [toolbox](http://www.clojure-toolbox.com/) to find a parser that allows lexing as a separate concern.

Take, for example, [The Parsatron](https://github.com/youngnh/parsatron) (weighing only 262 loc)

```
(require '[the.parsatron ; sampling of available combinators 
            :refer [run token attempt many times choice always never >> eof]])

(defn matches? [parser input] 
  (run 
    (choice 
      (attempt (>> parser (eof) (always true))) 
      (always false))
    input))
```

Now define your pattern

```
(def odds-and-evens (>> (many (token odd?)) (times 2 (token even?))))
```

And test

```
(matches? odds-and-evens [1 1 2 2])   ;=> true
(matches? odds-and-evens [1 1 1 2 2]) ;=> true
(matches? odds-and-evens [1 1 2 2 2]) ;=> false
(matches? odds-and-evens [1 1 2])     ;=> false
```

From here you can add sugar to specify your pattern as desired.

Answer (score 2):

Too long for a comment:

If you're thinking of growing your own, you might find Brzozowski's article on [Derivatives of Regular Expressions](http://port70.net/~nsz/articles/classic/brzozowski_derivatives_of_regexp_1964.pdf) useful. It describes an efficient technique for converting a regular expression into a state machine that recognizes it. An alternative source is John Conway's book [Regular Algebra and Finite Machines](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=1KAXc5TpEV8C&dq=John%20Conway%20%22Regular%20Expressions%20and%20Finite%20Machines%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=xAhRU7u9LM6wPPHRgNAH&ved=0CDUQ6AEwAA).

I've a feeling that [Christopher Grand's GitHub project](https://github.com/cgrand/regex), found by @leontalbot, has done the work already, but as I don't have a proper development environment to hand, I can't investigate. Although his terminal classes are strings, he defines a protocol for regexes that his unions and sequences (and stars?) comply with.

Looking around other languages.

- Scala does what Clojure does: wrap the Java regexes.
- The Boost folk have something for C++. It's not clear whether it
  requires the terminals to be characters.

Sorry I can't be more helpful.

---

Added notes:

- [This thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/clojure/vgvV7aAXlPs) on the Google group is worth reading.
- Russ Cox has collected some references on [Implementing Regular
  Expressions](http://swtch.com/~rsc/regexp/) probably more useful than those above.
- The [NFA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nondeterministic_finite_automaton) technique described in his own article [Regular Expression
  Matching Can Be Simple And Fast](http://swtch.com/~rsc/regexp/regexp1.html), referred to in the Google group
  thread, looks natural for Clojure.

Comment: Thanks for the summary. I do want to write one myself one day.. Those those links are going to be really helpful!